# Load files/folders in client machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load all files/folder under path in client machine using jquery. Can we do that? It looks like file browser of window but I want to custom style for it.

Comment: Or browser can request permission to access local files/folders?

Answer (score 1):

Cant be done.  Browsers cant access client machine file system.